# R: Interpolate y for rising and falling limbs for the same x

Tags: r, interpolation

I get a x,y data which is a clockwise loop. Within R I want to determine mid-point x-value (`Xmid`) and then interpolate y-value on both limbs for the same `Xmid`.

```
x <- c(1.62, 1.82,2.09, 2.48, 2.19, 1.87, 1.67)
y <- c(238, 388, 721, 744, 307, 246, 222)

plot(x, y, type = 'l')

mid <- function(x){
  0.5*(max(x, na.rm = T) - min(x, na.rm = T)) + min(x,na.rm = T)
}
```

But! When I'm using `approx` function it returns only one y-value (for the rising limb). How to get the second (for the falling limb)? Maybe there is other functions which can do this?

```
> approx(x, y, xout = mid(x))
$x
[1] 2.05

$y
[1] 634.6364
```

In other words I'm trying to do this: a graphical example from [Lawler et al., 2006] is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQR66.jpg)

Comment: `approx()` only works with data from proper mathematical "functions" in order to be efficient. What you've plotted is not a function since a function needs to pass the [vertical line test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_line_test).

Comment: Building on MrFlick's comment, you could fudge this by breaking your vector into two separate pieces (for the example at least) and use `approx` on each segment.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not necessary to me to use `approx()` function. Maybe the another way to get this values exists? I don't want to break to separate vectors, cause for my dataset it's a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data isn't regular (it doesn't correspond to a "proper" function), you are going to have to find all the intersections yourself. I think you can do that with something like

```
target <- mid(x)
idx <- which(abs(diff(sign(x-target)))>0)
```

which finds all the pairs of points that lie on each side of your x value of interest, then you can extract the y value for each of those

```
f <- function(i, target) approx(c(x[i], x[i+1]), c(y[i], y[i+1]), xout=target)$y
yp <- sapply(idx, f, target=target)
```

Then you can plot the results

```
abline(v=target, lty=2)
points(rep(target, length(yp)), yp, col="red", cex=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps. By the way, why are you using `$y` in the end of `f` function?

Comment: Because approx returns a list with values for x and y and we only want the y value.